# If the total space of circle bundle over hyperbolic manifold admits Riemannain metric of non-positive sectional curvature?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry

If the total space of circle bundle over higher genus surface admit Riemannian metric of non-positive sectional curvature?
  I wish to use the result about the  question and find Leeb's work [*3-manifolds with(out) metrics of nonpositive curvature*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1358977)   relate it. But  I can not understand the paper since I am a novice in 3-dimension manifold, so I ask for help .

Leeb asked in 1995: *which compact aspherical 
3-manifolds admit Riemannian metrics of nonpositive sectional curvature?*   Do we know more results about the question though the progress of those years in 3-manifold?

Add: Thanks to Thiku's answer, it is clearly for aspherical 3-manifold. It may too ambitious to ask *which compact aspherical smooth
n-manifolds (n>3) admit Riemannian metrics of nonpositive sectional curvature?*, since Davis and Januszkiewicz proved some exotic aspherical closed manifolds in the paper  *[Hyperbolization of polyhedra](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?extend=1&l=100&pg1=INDI&s1=93735&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=34&mx-pid=1131435)*. For example, *for each n≥4 there exists an aspherical closed n-dimensional manifold such that its universal covering is not homeomorphic to n-dimension Euclid space.*  So I reduce it  to the following questions:

1) If the total space of circle bundle over closed manifold with Riemannian metric of non-positive sectional curvature also admits Riemannian metric of non-positive sectional curvature?

2) If the total space of fiber bundle over circle, which the  fiber are closed manifold with Riemannian metric of non-positive sectional curvature, also admits  Riemannian metric of non-positive sectional curvature?

3) In general, given the fiber bundle with fiber and base space are closed manifolds with Riemannian metric of non-positive sectional curvature, if its total space also admits  Riemannian metric of non-positive sectional curvature?

Comment: The paper you cite completely solves the problem except for the case of closed graph manifolds. The latter case seems to be solved in http://m.mathnet.ru/links/8f77e6d1ef31437a2b3a52664f36aead/aa556.pdf

Comment: But if you are only interested in circle bundles, then actually Section 2.3 of Leeb‘s paper already does the job.

Comment: 1. Only virtually trivial circle bundles admit NPC metrics. For 2 and 3: Sometimes yes, sometimes not, but there are no general theorems (in higher dimensions).